# How to add a timer for images in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've been working on this code which displays the next traffic light when a button is pressed. Now I am trying to diplay the images in the array every 3 seconds. I have tried using setTimeOut in my code but my code juts stays on the first traffic light.

code:
  EDIT(FIXED)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>  

  <h1>JavaScript Code</h1> 
  <p>Traffic Light</p> 

<img id="traffic" src="only red1.jpg">
  <button type="button" onclick="ChangeLight()">Change Light</button>  



  <script> 
    var list = ["only red1.jpg","red-yellow 2.jpg", "green3.jpg","yellowonly4.jpg"];
    var nextlight = 0;
    var timer;
    function ChangeLight() {
      nextlight = nextlight + 1;      
      if (nextlight == list.length) 
        nextlight = 0;      
      var firstlight = document.getElementById('traffic');     
      firstlight.src = list[nextlight]; 
    } 


     timer = setInterval(ChangeLight, 3000);
  </script>  
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use `setInterval()` it will save having to set the timeout over and over? Also you want to pass the function name not a string so no need for double quotes. `setTimeout(ChangeLight, 3000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
timer = setInterval("ChangeLight", 3000);
```

Put it out of the function ^^

Comment: check edit pls , still not changing every 3 seconds.

Comment: you didn't do what i wrote here

Comment: what do you mean out of the function, out of the brackets ?

Comment: YES MARCO U DID ITTTT ( remove the speech marksfor it to work) hahaha nice thank youououououo ;))))

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change `timer = setTimeout("ChangeLight", 3000);` into `timer = setTimeout(ChangeLight, 3000);`.

Comment: its still not changing automatically. check edit please.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. It's supposed to be `setInterval(ChangeLight, 3000);`
2. `timer` is **inside** the `ChangeLight` function. You should move it outside.